# Rows.update data extension function

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, update

What is the error in this code:

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="get">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1");
    try {
        var resident = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey");
        var res;
        res = resident+'-PROMOTIONAL_EMAIL';
        var PrefDE = DataExtension.Init("external key here");
        var value = PrefDE.Rows.Update({preference_value:'False'},['resident_preference_id'], [res]);
    }
    catch(e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }
</script>
```

I am getting this error:

> There was an error updating the row(s)

There is something wrong in `rows.update` function `Attribute.GetValue` is working fine.

Comment: please share the layout of your "PrefDE". Syntax looks fine, it might have to do with  the DE.

Comment: The DE is "Preference_DE", column names are: 1. resident_id 2. preference_value 3. preference_name 4. resident_preference_id(this is primary key combination of resident_id and preference_name). and few more columns.

Comment: It's a shared DE

Comment: It's a shared DE. If the syntax is correct what could be the problem with DE. I tried this with two different DE's one shared and one normal, but it's not working with both. Lookup function is working fine but rows update not.

Comment: is `resident_preference_id` the only Primary key?

Comment: yes this is the only primary key

Comment: actually this is not working for shared DE only, i created a new DE in contact builder with same fields and its working.

Comment: If it is a shared DE, then it is located in Parent BU. Meaning that you have to either perform this operation in Parent, or establish the context otherwise.

Comment: Thankyou for your help! , How to establish the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you are attempting to use `rows.Update` from child BU on a Shared DE.
Shared DE location means it is treated like being located in parent.

Your code does not work as you are in the wrong context (child trying to update parent). This can be done though using the "ENT." prefix. (= ENTerprise context)

It's just that the function `Rows.Update`, which is in the SSJS Core Library, works on the customerkey of the Data Extension, which cannot be prefixed with "ENT.".

Once you use a method that works with the *name* of the DE - SSJS Platform functions or AMPScript - you can use the ENT.prefix before the data extension name like `Platform.Function.UpsertData("ENT.myDE", ...)` to do exactly that. It does not help the other way around (from parent to child).

Here is an example with a Shared DE that has one PK (subKey) and one other field, executed successfully on a cloudpage in child BU.

You actually don't need the `Platform.Load("Core",1)` bit here, as we are not using a *Core*, but a Platform Function, which works without loading the Core library. I'll include it regardless as your other code might need it.

```
<script runat="server" type="javascript">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
  try {
      Platform.Function.UpsertDE("ENT.jltest",["subKey"],["777777"],["Email"],["myemail@example.com"])
    
} catch (err) {
    Write(Stringify(err));
  
}
</script>
```

Whether upsertDE or upsertData is right for your usecase depends.
for brevity's sake let's just say upsertDE is for cloudpages, upsertData is for emails.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertData.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpdateDE.htm