# Access Data Extensions in SJSS script

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

In this code:

```
if (authobj.access_token) {
    var del = HTTP.Post(authobj.rest_instance_url+'contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference', 'application/json', '{"deleteOperationType":"ContactAndAttributes","targetList":{"listKey":"FCB3B86A-19F3-4AA8-9C11-E129258C4938","listType":{"listTypeID":3}},"deleteListWhenCompleted":false,"deleteListContentsWhenCompleted":true}', ["Authorization"], ["Bearer " + authobj.access_token]);
    var delobj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(del.Response[0]);
    if (delobj.hasErrors == false) {
        var de = DataExtension.Init("36EDECC1-4BEA-4E2E-B333-3983173F7F89");
        de.Rows.Add({ResponseDateTime:delobj.responseDateTime,RowCount:delobj.targetListInformation.rowCount});
    }
};
```

I'm trying to get to 2 different data extensions by their listkey. Is the format for the listkey correct? Or should I remove the hyphens?

Comment: The customerKey (here "listkey") stays unchanged from what you can see it on the UI, i.e. you do not need to remove any hyphens.

Comment: @JonasLamberty great, thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: I'm getting an error on this script when I run it in an automation. It only says it's a runtime error. I don't see any errors in the code and my Install package is configured correctly. How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: try / catch. nevermind the context, just check the code snippet here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358890/rows-update-data-extension-function/359035#359035

you can do this on a cloudpage and output errors, or you insert errormessages into a DE if you need to test inside an automation.

Comment: @JonasLamberty Great, I will try those approaches. Guess I can add an Else statement at the end and output the errors there. Thanks.