# UpsertDE function not working on Shared Data Extension using SSJS from child BU even though used ENT

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, ssjs, upsert

I want to use UpsertDE function on Shared Data Extension using SSJS from child BU. Even I tried ENT. before DE name, I have received 500 error in cloud page and script activity is getting errored in Automation Studio.

If i use DE within same child BU, it is working fine. I am facing issue with shared DE

Below is my code:

```html
<script runat="server" language="javascript" excutioncontexttype="get">
Platform.Load("core","1");
Platform.Function.UpsertDE("[ENT.SharedDEname]",["Date"],[Now()],["FName","Lname","Status"],["value1","value2","value3"]);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use the external key not the name of the DE in UpsertDE() I believe. That might be the issue you are having. I also would put this on a CloudPage and wrap in a `try {  ... } catch(e) { Write(Stringify(e)) }` to have it output the cause of the 500 error for easier debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't quite explain the same code working in child BU, I do see  simple syntax error in your case:

```
"[ENT.SharedDEname]"
```

should not be an array but

```
"ENT.SharedDEname"
```

Which makes sense, the arrays are meant to accomodate "lists of things" - but this  will be exactly one DE. Whereas the fields - primary keys and others - can be more than 1 and the array helps with that.

Platform.Function.UpsertDE and similar functions (insert, lookup, lookuprows), do work on DE name ([reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358890/rows-update-data-extension-function/359035#359035)), these SSJS Platform functions "mirror" AMPScript in capability (in that they do work by data extension name, and they do support "ENT.").

See a functional example of pretty much your usecase in the answer here:
[Rows.update data extension function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/358890/rows-update-data-extension-function/359035#359035)

==

UpsertData's SSJS cousin "rows.add" from the Core library leverages the customerKey, where the ENT prefix simply "does not apply" and you couldn't do this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRowsAdd.html

Comment: Thanks Jonas. It helped.

Comment: nice - please accept the answer it the question is resolved for you :)

Comment: Thanks. Accepted it